# SQL Clauses for Columns within Views

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am looking at building a view which has clauses with the column, so if certain parameters are met, then it will set a flag as 1.
I am not sure if I am misunderstanding how a case works in this scenario, however this is what I have:

```
select t.[Ticket_ClientId] as ClientID
      ,t.[Ticket_CallerId] as CallerID
      ,t.[Ticket_RecordTypeId] as RecordTypeID
      ,t.[Ticket_Id] as TicketRawID
      ,t.[Ticket_OwnerId] as TicketOwner
      ,t.[Ticket_LocationId] as LocationID
      ,t.[Ticket_LastActionId] as LastAction
      ,t.[Ticket_OpenDate] as OpenDate
      ,t.[Ticket_CloseDate] as CloseDate
      ,t.[Ticket_LastModifiedDate] as LastModified
      ,t.[Ticket_LocationName] as LocationName
      ,t.[Ticket_Solution] as Solution
      ,t.[Ticket_PriorityName] as [Priority]
      ,t.[Ticket_TakenByName] as TakenBy
      ,t.[Ticket_GroupName] as [Group]
      ,t.[Ticket_ClientName] as Client
      ,t.[Ticket_StatusName] as [Status]
      ,t.[Ticket_DisplayId] as TicketID
      ,t.[Ticket_CallerName] as [Caller]
      ,t.[Ticket_CallerPhone] as CallerPhone
      ,t.[Ticket_CallerEmail] as CallerEmail
      ,t.[Ticket_Description] as [Description]
      ,t.[Ticket_RecordTypeNameSingular] as RecordType
      ,t.[Ticket_Title] as Title
      ,t.[Ticket_CloseSLATargetDate] as TargetClose
      ,t.[Ticket_CloseSLATimeRemaining] as CloseTimeRemaining
      ,t.[Ticket_CloseSLACompleteDate] as CloseCompleteDate
      ,t.[Ticket_NextSLATargetDate] as NextSLATarget
      ,t.[Ticket_Resolved] as Reolved
      ,t.[Ticket_ResolvedDate] as ResolvedDate
      ,t.[Ticket_CloseSLADurationOnComplete] as CloseSLADurationComplete
      ,t.[Ticket_WithinResponseSLA] as WithinResponseSLA
      ,t.[Ticket_WithinDiagnoseSLA] as WithinDiagnoseSLA
      ,t.[Ticket_WithinCloseSLA] as WithinCloseSLA
      ,t.[Ticket_WithinNextSLA] as WithinNextSLA
      ,t.[Ticket_CloseSLATargetDuration] as CloseSLATargetDuration
      ,t.[Ticket_CloseSLAElapsedTime] As CloseSLAElapsedTime
      ,t.[Ticket_UpdateDate] As [Update]
      ,t.[Ticket_CreatedByCallerName] as CreatedBy
      ,t.[Ticket_CategoryName] as QueueName
      ,t.[Ticket_PortalName] as PortalName
      ,case t.[TicketOpen]  when t.ticket_closedate is null and ticket_opendate is not null then 1 else 0 end
      ,case t.[TicketClosed] when t.ticket_closedate is not null and ticket_opendate is null then 1 else 0 end
from dbo.Ticket t
where cast(t.Ticket_LastModifiedDate as date) >= cast(getdate()-7 as date)
```

I have tried to move the case clauses below my where clause however that did not work either.

Please can someone advise.
Thanks

Comment: What isn't working about what you have then?

Comment: @cai120. the formation of Case statement needed to be altered a little. 
CASE WHEN (t.ticket_closedate is null and ticket_opendate is not null) THEN 1
             ELSE 0 END AS  [TicketStatus]  
You will not need two case statements. If you want two different column names you can use a sub query instead of CASE statement here.

Comment: Because your second case statement is exactly similar to your first case statement else clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are syntax errors in those conditional columns. Please check below query.

```
select t.[Ticket_ClientId] as ClientID
      ,t.[Ticket_CallerId] as CallerID
      ,t.[Ticket_RecordTypeId] as RecordTypeID
      ,t.[Ticket_Id] as TicketRawID
      ,t.[Ticket_OwnerId] as TicketOwner
      ,t.[Ticket_LocationId] as LocationID
      ,t.[Ticket_LastActionId] as LastAction
      ,t.[Ticket_OpenDate] as OpenDate
      ,t.[Ticket_CloseDate] as CloseDate
      ,t.[Ticket_LastModifiedDate] as LastModified
      ,t.[Ticket_LocationName] as LocationName
      ,t.[Ticket_Solution] as Solution
      ,t.[Ticket_PriorityName] as [Priority]
      ,t.[Ticket_TakenByName] as TakenBy
      ,t.[Ticket_GroupName] as [Group]
      ,t.[Ticket_ClientName] as Client
      ,t.[Ticket_StatusName] as [Status]
      ,t.[Ticket_DisplayId] as TicketID
      ,t.[Ticket_CallerName] as [Caller]
      ,t.[Ticket_CallerPhone] as CallerPhone
      ,t.[Ticket_CallerEmail] as CallerEmail
      ,t.[Ticket_Description] as [Description]
      ,t.[Ticket_RecordTypeNameSingular] as RecordType
      ,t.[Ticket_Title] as Title
      ,t.[Ticket_CloseSLATargetDate] as TargetClose
      ,t.[Ticket_CloseSLATimeRemaining] as CloseTimeRemaining
      ,t.[Ticket_CloseSLACompleteDate] as CloseCompleteDate
      ,t.[Ticket_NextSLATargetDate] as NextSLATarget
      ,t.[Ticket_Resolved] as Reolved
      ,t.[Ticket_ResolvedDate] as ResolvedDate
      ,t.[Ticket_CloseSLADurationOnComplete] as CloseSLADurationComplete
      ,t.[Ticket_WithinResponseSLA] as WithinResponseSLA
      ,t.[Ticket_WithinDiagnoseSLA] as WithinDiagnoseSLA
      ,t.[Ticket_WithinCloseSLA] as WithinCloseSLA
      ,t.[Ticket_WithinNextSLA] as WithinNextSLA
      ,t.[Ticket_CloseSLATargetDuration] as CloseSLATargetDuration
      ,t.[Ticket_CloseSLAElapsedTime] As CloseSLAElapsedTime
      ,t.[Ticket_UpdateDate] As [Update]
      ,t.[Ticket_CreatedByCallerName] as CreatedBy
      ,t.[Ticket_CategoryName] as QueueName
      ,t.[Ticket_PortalName] as PortalName
      ,(case when t.ticket_closedate is null and ticket_opendate is not null then 1 else 0 end) [TicketOpen]
      ,(case when t.ticket_closedate is not null and ticket_opendate is null then 1 else 0 end) [TicketClosed] 
from dbo.Ticket t
where cast(t.Ticket_LastModifiedDate as date) >= cast(getdate()-7 as date)
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help.

Comment: You are most welcome. You did great job. Best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
,case when t.ticket_closedate is null and t.ticket_opendate is not null then 1 else 0 end as [TicketOpen] 
,case  when t.ticket_closedate is not null and t.ticket_opendate is null then 1 else 0 end as [TicketClosed]
from dbo.Ticket t
where cast(t.Ticket_LastModifiedDate as date) >= cast(getdate()-7 as date)
```

We are able to resolve the reported issue. We found issue is due to 'case/when/then' in the shared query... please replace your query with 'case/when/then' share by us and see if it resolve the issue.

We executed and found to be working... Please check and acknowledge

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate it